# wpf dataGrid binding selecteditem not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, selecteditem

I'm tryng to bind the selectedItem of a datagrid with a property in MVVM.
the problem is that it does not fire the "Set" of the property.

in the xaml part i have:

```
 <WPFCtrlDg:ExtDataGrid Name="_edgMessage" Grid.Row="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LNE_MESSAGE, Mode=OneWay}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentMessage, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

in the code part:

```
 private LNE_MESSAGE _currentMessage;
    public LNE_MESSAGE CurrentMessage
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentMessage == null)
            {
                ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LNE_MESSAGE);
                if (collectionView != null)
                    return collectionView.CurrentItem as LNE_MESSAGE;
                return null;
            }
            return _currentMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LNE_MESSAGE);
            if (collectionView != null)
                collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(value);

            _currentMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentMessage);
        }
    }
```

the extdatagrid is a custom control and the selected item property is done this way:

```
        public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(ExtDataGrid),
                                new UIPropertyMetadata((s, e) => 
                                                                {
                                                                    ExtDataGrid extDg = s as ExtDataGrid;
                                                                    Debug.Assert(extDg != null);
                                                                    extDg.CurrentItem = e.NewValue;
                                                                }));
```

any idea of how to bind correctly the selecteditem property?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your datacontext is being set right. 
And debug and see locals window to see, if datacontext is actually being set by using the visual helper. Also see output window for any binding errors.

At first sight your dependency property looks right.

Comment: the locals window where you can see your parameters when debugging  see this => http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/29/using-the-wpf-tree-visualizer-vstipdebug0004.aspx

Comment: both windows are empy (don't know if I need to print something on teh output). btw tha datagrid load its content conrrectly with LNE_MESSAGE property which is in the same viewmodel than CurrentMessage, so I think the datacontext is correct

Comment: CurrentMessage is always set to the first item in the datagrid and it never changes even if the selection changes

Comment: debug your dependency property and see if it gets inside the set

Comment: no it does not. it just register the dependency property when the datagrid is loaded, but it never enters in get or set method